# Alternate link colors on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

I've looked around here already and I can't find anything that answers my question or that actually works, so maybe some of you can give me a solution for this.

I'm creating a blog template and I'd like that the posts' links show two different colors on hover, alternated. Say, link1 hovers on red, link2 hovers on green, link3 hovers on red again, link4 on green, and so on.

How can I make this happen?

**EDIT:** Someone removed the part where I mentioned I had already researched about this, I don't why they did that.

Here's the code I found in another question, which is not working:

```
body:nth-child(odd) a:hover{ background-color:#dedede; color: #996633; }
body:nth-child(even) a:hover{ background-color:none; color : #FF0000}
```

Also, I apologize if my question has annoyed some of you. It wasn't my intention. There was no need to be rude though.

Comment: Please provide some sort of code so we know what you've tried so far. We aren't here to write your code for you, but to instead help fix what you've written so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the [:nth-child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) in your css:

```
a:nth-child(odd):hover {
color: red;
}

a:nth-child(even):hover {
color: green;
}
```

Working [fiddle here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mf0d4obz/).

Answer (score 1):

**try it**

```
a:hover.altlink{
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide us some code so we can help, but there are numerous ways this can be done, you could use nth-child to select each link and assign a different color, you can add specific classes to your links each of which has a different hover effect. you could even use data attributes referenced in your css.

Please provide code so we can help out more.

```
.link:nth-child(1):hover {color:blue;}
.link:nth-child(2):hover {color:red;}
```

or

```
<a href="#" class="link link--blue"></a>
<a href="#" class="link link--red"></a>
```

etc